# Encounter error while trying to login Azure virtual machine through mysql

Tags: mysql, .net, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a VM in azure. Deployed my asp .net mvc application. Installed MySQL and restored my database. now when I login in my application I get the following error

•Invalid DB Connection. Please Check - the errorAuthentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'fe80::5104:58d5:a59f:8159%11' (using password: NO)

I supplied the correct user id and password in my application. But still I don't know why it is giving error. I also set Limits to host matching setting to %. I checked what this fe80::5104:58d5:a59f:8159%11 and it looks like its link local ipv6 address. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Can you show your connection string (change some parts for security)?

Comment: @Peter  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Projects>
  <Project>
    <Name>DigiTrace</Name>
    <Description>DigiTrace</Description>
    <DevelopmentLanguage>JSON</DevelopmentLanguage>
    <DatabaseType>MySQL</DatabaseType>
    <ConnectionString>Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=latestdigitracedb;Uid=root;Pwd=change#1234</ConnectionString>
    <InputRegulation>C:\Users\556993\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DigiTrace\DigiTrace\2012-1728</InputRegulation>
  </Project>
</Projects>

Comment: Any news, @SARAVAN?